# Simpler syntax to invoke a template functor

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I have a functor that looks like this:

```
struct Functor {
  template<typename T, typename... Args> static void func( Args&&... args );
};
```

I need to pass it as a template parameter to a function and this function invokes it:

```
template<typename F> void fn() {
  F::template func<int>(1, 2, 3);
}
fn<Functor>();
```

Having to write `F::template func<int>` feels tedious, and I need to call it many times in many different functions. I would love to be able to write something more concise, like `F<int>(1, 2, 3)`.

Is there any way to sugarcoat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is to let all template deducible, something like:

```
template <typename> struct tag{};

struct Functor {
  template<typename T, typename... Args> static void func(tag<T>,  Args&&... args );
};
```

And so, usage is similar to:

```
template<typename F> void fn() {
  F::func(tag<int>{}, 1, 2, 3);
}
fn<Functor>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `F` as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct Functor {
  template<typename... Args> void operator() ( Args&&... args );
};
```

and receive `F` as a template-template parameter in `fn()`

```
template <template <typename> class F>
void fn ()
 { F<int>{}(1, 2, 3); }

fn<Functor>();
```

But I don't know if it's a good idea: you reduce the typewriting but need an instance of `F<int>` that isn't needed using a static method.

Comment: Nice idea! Why is it a problem to create an instance of `F<int>`? I'm sure the compiler will optimize it away. I'll try playing with this for a bit and will accept the answer if I decide to go with it :)

Comment: The switch to `operator()` isn't necessary btw, `F<int>::func(1, 2, 3)`. (even if using `operator()` for functor is common).